# How to get values at the same index across multiple sub lists?

Tags: c#

I have a function that goes out to a website and scrapes some data and returns a list of lists with that data. What I need help with is getting the correct values from across the sub lists and mapping that to the PlayerStats object. Essentially all the data at index[0] across the lists would be related and belong to the same player. Same with index[1] and so on.

```
public List<List<string>> GetPlayerStatsFromNbaReference()
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_per_game.html");

        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        List<string> positions = new List<string>();
        List<string> teams = new List<string>();
        List<string> minutes = new List<string>();
        List<string> fieldGoalAttempts = new List<string>();
        List<string> fieldGoalMakes = new List<string>();
        List<string> threePointAttempts = new List<string>();
        List<string> threepointMakes = new List<string>();
        List<string> freeThrowAttempts = new List<string>();
        List<string> freeThrowMakes = new List<string>();
        List<string> freeThrowPercentage = new List<string>();
        List<string> rebounds = new List<string>();
        List<string> offensiveRebounds = new List<string>();
        List<string> defensiveRebounds = new List<string>();
        List<string> assists = new List<string>();
        List<string> steals = new List<string>();
        List<string> blocks = new List<string>();
        List<string> points = new List<string>();

        var playerName = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='player']/a");
        var playerPosition = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='pos']");
        var playerTeam = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='team_id']/a");
        var playerMinutesPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='mp_per_g']");
        var playerFieldGoalAttemptsPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='fga_per_g']");
        var playerFieldgoalMakesPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='fg_per_g']");
        var playerThreePointAttemptsPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='fg3a_per_g']");
        var playerThreePointMakesPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='fg3_per_g']");
        var playerFreeThrowAttemptsPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='fta_per_g']");
        var playerFreeThrowMakesPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='ft_per_g']");
        var playerFreeThrowPercentage = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='ft_pct']");
        var playerReboundsPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='trb_per_g']");
        var playerOffenseiveReboundsPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='orb_per_g']");
        var playerDefensiveReboundsPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='drb_per_g']");
        var playerAssistsPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='ast_per_g']");
        var playerStealsPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='stl_per_g']");
        var playerBlocksPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='blk_per_g']");
        var playerPointsPerGame = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-stat='pts_per_g']");

        foreach(var name in playerName)
        {
            names.Add(name.InnerText);
        }

        foreach(var pos in playerPosition)
        {
            positions.Add(pos.InnerText);
        }

        foreach (var team in playerTeam)
        {
            teams.Add(team.InnerText);
        }

        foreach(var min in playerMinutesPerGame)
        {
            minutes.Add(min.InnerText);
        }

        List<List<string>> playerStats = new List<List<string>>()
        {
            names,
            positions,
            teams,
            minutes,
            fieldGoalAttempts,
            fieldGoalMakes,
            threePointAttempts,
            threepointMakes,
            freeThrowAttempts,
            freeThrowMakes,
            freeThrowPercentage,
            rebounds,
            offensiveRebounds,
            defensiveRebounds,
            assists,
            steals,
            blocks,
            points
        };


        return playerStats;
    }
}


public class PlayerStats
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set;}
    public decimal MinutesPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal FieldGoalAttemptsPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal FieldgoalMakesPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal ThreePointAttemptsPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal ThreePointMakesPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal ThrowAttemptsPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal ThrowMakesPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal FreeThrowPercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal ReboundsPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal OffenseiveReboundsPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal DefensiveReboundsPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal AssistsPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal StealsPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal BlocksPerGame { get; set; }
    public decimal PointsPerGame { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  If you know how to get an element from a list by index, what's stopping you from repeating that process across multiple lists?

Comment: You might consider a player object to store the data elements so you only need one list.  Cleaner, neater, OO, simpler and obviates the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't the best way to do it but this is how I solved my issue.

```
var output = (names.Zip(teams, (first, second) => new { Name = first, Team = second })
                           .Zip(positions, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = second })
                           .Zip(minutes, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = second })
                           .Zip(fieldGoalAttempts, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = second })
                           .Zip(fieldGoalMakes, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = second })
                           .Zip(threePointAttempts, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = first.FGM, TPA = second })
                           .Zip(threepointMakes, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = first.FGM, TPA = first.TPA, TPM = second })
                           .Zip(freeThrowAttempts, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = first.FGM, TPA = first.TPA, TPM = first.TPM, FTA = second })
                           .Zip(freeThrowMakes, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = first.FGM, TPA = first.TPA, TPM = first.TPM, FTA = first.FTA, FTM = second })
                           .Zip(freeThrowPercentage, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = first.FGM, TPA = first.TPA, TPM = first.TPM, FTA = first.FTA, FTM = second })
                           .Zip(rebounds, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = first.FGM, TPA = first.TPA, TPM = first.TPM, FTA = first.FTA, FTM = first.FTM, Rebounds = second})
                           .Zip(defensiveRebounds, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = first.FGM, TPA = first.TPA, TPM = first.TPM, FTA = first.FTA, FTM = first.FTM, Rebounds = first.Rebounds, Dreb = second })
                           .Zip(offensiveRebounds, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = first.FGM, TPA = first.TPA, TPM = first.TPM, FTA = first.FTA, FTM = first.FTM, Rebounds = first.Rebounds, Dreb = first.Dreb, Oreb = second })
                           .Zip(assists, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = first.FGM, TPA = first.TPA, TPM = first.TPM, FTA = first.FTA, FTM = first.FTM, Rebounds = first.Rebounds, Dreb = first.Dreb, Oreb = first.Oreb, Assists = second })
                           .Zip(steals, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = first.FGM, TPA = first.TPA, TPM = first.TPM, FTA = first.FTA, FTM = first.FTM, Rebounds = first.Rebounds, Dreb = first.Dreb, Oreb = first.Oreb, Assists = first.Assists, Steals = second })
                           .Zip(blocks, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minutes = first.Minutes, FGA = first.FGA, FGM = first.FGM, TPA = first.TPA, TPM = first.TPM, FTA = first.FTA, FTM = first.FTM, Rebounds = first.Rebounds, Dreb = first.Dreb, Oreb = first.Oreb, Assists = first.Assists, Steals = first.Steals, Blocks = second })
                           .Zip(points, (first, second) => new { Name = first.Name, Team = first.Team, Position = first.Position, Minu
```